How to wait until element is visible in Cypress without using timeout
How to wait until element is visible in Cypress without using timeout.
Currently I am using the following method, but I don't need time and interval:
Cypress.Commands.add('waitForElementPresent', (locator, time, inter) => {
cy.waitUntil(() => {
    return Cypress.$(locator).length
  }, {timeout:time,
interval:inter})
  })

But this method will wait till the time we provided. But I need a method which can wait till element is visible without timeout.
I need to test this scenario so that I can record the time taken for the element to visible.

You don't need waituntil, this functionality is built into all Cypress queries.
cy.get(locator).should('be.visible')  

// or :visible added to locator

cy.get(`${locator}:visible`)

// with loner timeout

cy.get(locator, {timeout:10_000})  // wait up to 10 seconds
  .should('be.visible') 

cypress-recurse is a more modern version of waitunitl. It is easier to understand and has better documentation.
